# Some freeware tool or script to fetch the MS SQL Server Edition

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I need to check "*Microsoft SQL Server Edition*"  e.g. *Standard, Express or Enterprise* etc installed on multiple systems, but to get the edition details I manually execute `@@version` query on each *SQL Server Management Studio* window or console. Is there is any freeware tool or script which checks the edition of edition of MS SQL Server from backend without manually executing the query.